# Transform Postgress JSONB column to another JSONB format

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Lets say I have a column called words:
It looks like this:

```
{
    "enterprise": [
        {
            "name": "bin",
            "type": 0,
            "props": {"score": 1, "id": "bin"},
            "status": "supported"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "bist",
            "type": 0,
            "props": {"score": 1, "id": "bin"},
            "status": "unsupported"
        }],
    "private": [
        {
            "name": "hello",
            "type": 0,
            "props": {"score": 1, "id": "hello"},
            "status": "supported"
        },
        {
            "name": "hello",
            "type": 0,
            "props": {"score": 1, "id": "hello"},
            "status": "supported"
        }
    ]
}
```

It can also be partially empty

```
{
  "enterprise": [],
  "private": []
}
```

NEW format should be this: Every object in array from previous format is grouped by `props.id` field into new object where old `name` field is appended into `words` array. `exclude` field is filled with `name` field from objects that have `status`=unsupported.

```
{
  "private": [
    {
      id: "bin",
      score: 1,
      visible: false, 
      words: ["bin", "bist"],
      other: [], 
      exclude: [] 
    }
  ]
}
```

I am aware that I would need some reduce sql json function because I am converting from flat structure to nested, but don't know exactly where to look at.

Comment: Desired final data state must match source data completely! And explain in details the algorithm, especially about the source of final data which is not present in source data.

Comment: Every object in array from previous format is grouped by `props.id` field into new object where old `name` field is appended into `words` array. @Akina. `Exclude` array is filled with strings from status field. `other` is empty array, 
 visible is false, score is from old one

Comment: *Exclude array is filled with strings from status field.* - where is this status field?

Comment: @Akina Sorry, I added it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross join` to transform the JSON data, and then perform several aggregations of the flattened result, grouping on the IDs and keys:

```sql
with cte(key, id, score, name, status) as (
   select v1.key::text, (v.value -> 'props' -> 'id')::text, (v.value -> 'props' -> 'score')::text, v.value -> 'name' , (v.value -> 'status')::text
   from tbl t cross join json_each(t.words) v1 cross join json_array_elements(v1.value) v
)   
select jsonb_pretty(json_build_object(t2.key, t2.js)::jsonb) 
from (select t1.key, json_agg(json_build_object('id', t1.id, 'score', t1.m, 'visible', false, 'words', t1.a, 'other', '[]'::json, 'exclude', t1.a1)) js 
    from (select c.key, c.id, max(c.score::int) m, json_agg(c.name) a, coalesce(json_agg(c.name) filter (where c.status = '"unsupported"'), '[]'::json) a1
          from cte c group by c.key, c.id) t1 group by t1.key) t2
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=723c0b8b7d149c6fef943715898038d8).

Comment: tnx, I forgot to add that unsupported array is filled from status field in old format.

Comment: And this should update the column

Comment: @Alexa What is the `unsupported` key in your new data format? Your current new keys are `other` and `exclude`. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Actually, I meant to say `exclude`.

Comment: @Alexa Please see my recent edit.

Comment: This result is not ok since I am getting 2 objects. In reality it should be one object with keys "private" and "enterprise". And also update should update only data inside a single  row not aggregate data across table.